# SharePoint Migration and Invalid Modified By / Created By users update

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

We have found that ShareGate is able to migrate data for user accounts which have been removed from AD, so for example post migration we can see that Jonathan Bond modified a document in Jan 2015 even though he’s now left the business.

When we run the aggregation tool we have not been able to preserve these field values, and so they have reverted to the user executing the tool.

the challenge, work out how we can add an a user whose account has been deleted to the created by / modified by fields … I wonder if it’s a case of writing just a string value in?

Sharegate and other migration toll are able to retail user values eventhough user does not exist in AD/SharePoint not sure how to achieve it?

Comment: I don't think you can preserve those values even Migration tool will not help you. Because it will try to find user in AD and if its not there it will replace with tool running account ( you can mapped it to other account)

Comment: thanks for info, but we can see user values are being preserved by Sharegate eventhough user does not exist on new tenant and if migration tool are being able to do so then there must be way to preserve values

Comment: you are migrating from which tenant to which  using Sharegate ?

Comment: We are migrating from one SharePoint online tenant to another and we are using Sharegate Desktop: Sharegate Migration

Comment: Sharepoint list isn't checking directly AD it checks User Information List (hidden list on each site collection) if user isn't found then it uses EnsureUser so it is added to that list. I suspect that ShareGate is populating that list somehow, (but I thought you still require an account in AD). Compare User Information List before and after the execution of the ShareGate tool.

Comment: @MarekSarad, i did look at user information list and I cannot find user, also when I click on migrated item's user field it just saws an error occurred so I suspect migration toll is not adding user to user information list but somehow manage to add values on Created By and Modified By fields.

Comment: Are you using any user mapping file in Sharegate while migration?

Comment: @BhaskarDhone, there is no mapping file